# Is it possible to dominate all captains in a region?

Tags: middle-earth-shadow-of-war

Like the title says, can you dominate all captains within a certain region?  I'm currently trying to do this, though haven't been completely lucky with it so far (the random death advancing time, accidentally killing my target, and betrayals).  I've gotten about half the captains in the region where you capture your first fortress so far.

So, is it possible to do, provided with your current level (or by shaming) you are able to capture any Orc in the region you are currently?  If it is possible, does this also prevent more, <s>free-willed, undominated</s> unfriendly Orc from spawning?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do it rather frequently.

- Own the zone's fortress.  Links to the fortress provide stability within your forces. BTW: Minas Morgul will never be *yours* and "Iron Will" seems to be unusually common in new captains here, so just learn to embrace the chaos in this zone. FWIW: I tend to have 3-4 wild captains in Minas Morgul.
- Make your Captains feel like an important part of the team.  Promote/Infiltrate as many as you can to Warchief.  Make everyone else a bodyguard/spy to a Warchief.  Fortress ownership means jobs for all.  A pending Assault means up to 6 Assault Leader positions and up to 6 Warchief towers.  Each Enemy Warchief tower can either support 1 Infiltrator or 3 spies.  Infiltrators make your assault *much* easier.
- Support your Captains. Show up for their power struggles and protect them.  Don't let them bleed out during Assaults/Sieges.  For pit fights... well they're on their own there. (Homophone Hat-trick!)
- Punish betrayal.  Use "Worse than Death" on those who betray you.  A slavering reminder in your ranks of what happens to the disloyal seems to be a valuable tool.  FWIW: you'll gain this ability when you finish the "Bruze" quests.
- If you *do* let a supporter "die", make sure he doesn't come back without your assistance. If you're in Act 4, raise any dead captains that still have their clan affiliation.
- Know that killing the blood-brother of a tame captain will definitely cause that captain to rebel.  Just a trait to look out for.
- Don't die to a grunt when all your army slots are full of tame captains.  He'll be promoted and duel one of your existing captains for the slot.  And most importantly, It's just pathetic.

If you spend any length of time in a zone following these guidelines, before long, captains will stop rebelling, new captains will not have room to show up, and your own captains will stop participating in power struggles.

---

This stability can be a problem. As you gain experience, the captains in your stable zones will stagnate. So I also frequently kick the anthill.

- Taking captains with you in an Online Fortress Assault, gives them the opportunity to kill enemy captains and gain levels.  It also gives them the opportunity to die.
- To re-introduce more general excitement/promotions into a zone, take advantage of the local pit-fight arena.  At lower levels, sending one of your captains against new-blood can be rewarding, but before long, starting in Nurnen, even the "Champions" will be so unimpressive as to give your tame captain only a single level for defeating them.  At that point go to the Army screen and send two of your captains to the pits to fight each other, and don't raise the looser.  After 2 or 3 slots have opened up, advance time and you'll start seeing "wild" captains again.
- Defending against Act 4 sieges can be a source of deaths, promotions and new recruits reducing a zone's stability.
- Failing to defend against an Act 4 siege will do even more to reduce a zone's stability.

In any case, when trying to "level up" the orcs in a region, a confrontation between tame and wild captains may give a handful of levels to a victorious tame captain.  Alternatively, taming the wild orc with a white gem in your "rune" slot will give him a handful of levels, and he'll feel obliged to quickly go on 3 or 4 relatively easy hunts/trials for another handful of levels each.  Sometimes new blood is just easier.

Comment: Thank you for all the information!  I'll keep going and try to lock down region where you get your first base just so I don't have to worry about it.  Then go through your suggestions so that they Orcs there don't cap out at a low level.

Answer (score 0):

Iv'e gotten to points where i have dominated/converted all captains in an area and have done exactly what foxmcloud has stated and it works beautifully.

Most of my captains help eachother and i assist when able to. And assigning warchiefs and commanders actually makes them feel like more of a part of the system than a rogue. But i also find it helps to combine them with orcs that have abilities that compliment eachother and orcs that are related like brothers for they will both be loyal and they usually will always come to the aid of one another.

The best way i find is to assign 2-3 body guards to the main ones guarding the fortress and then work down to the weaker orcs that are assigned to the stronger ones and pretty much everyone is guarding someone who is really strong so they dont usaully die.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, if possible. But very difficult, since almost always you are about to get it you are betrayed by someone. But I got it. Although it was for a short time. But if you can make it, if you are lucky you can do it even fast enough